# Use Server image as the marker of google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

[image]I am working on an application where i need to show images that comes from server url, as the annotation(marker) on google map something like profile pic of the user. How to use a layout or custom view as the marker?

Thanks 
RawCoder

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OverlayItem.setMarker()`.

```
overlayItem.setMarker(icon);
```

Where `icon` is the `Drawable` you retrieve from your URL.

**EDIT** in addition to your comment and your edited question:

I'd recommend you add the one image you posted in your question in the resources drowables and use it as a basis drawable. The retrieve the custom image from your URL and overlay it onto the existing one creating a new drawable image which you'll be able to use with `setMarker()`.

The click will be caught by `Overlay.onTap()`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But i need something more. I have edited my question and added an image.Like this image i need to use a layout where i can put the server image. And also want to add click listener on that layout. how can i convert layout to marker drawable. Can you post some code??

Comment: Can you post some code of how can i get drawable from layout xml. And one more thing i need to plot lots of pin on map so i have to implement lazy loading of images otherwise it will take too much time to get the drawable from url and then plot on map. How can i do this lazy loading?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to implement this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070347/android-how-to-to-set-imageview-as-a-marker-in-google-map-api-android